# Alterar valores de variáveis em uma função através de outra função?

Tags: javascript

Como passar parâmetros de uma função a outra ?

Segue o código:

```html
<body onload="getfoucs()">
<select id="select_compra" data-limit="3">
 <option disabled selected style="display: none">Aaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
 <option>Bbbbbbbbb</option>
 <option>Ccccccc</option>
 <option>Ddddddddddd</option>
</select>
 <script>
function datalimit(limit)
{
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('[data-limit]');
    [].forEach.call
    (
     selects, function(select)
     {
        var limit = select.getAttribute('data-limit');
         [].forEach.call
         (
          select.options, function(option)
          {
        var text = option.innerHTML.substring(0, limit);
        option.innerHTML = text;
       }
      );
    }
   );
}
function getfoucs()
{
 datalimit();
 select_compra.addEventListener
 (
  'change', function()
  {
   datalimit(50);
   /*
   Como eu altero o valor de "limit" e
   Chamo novamente a função datalimit()
   */
  }
 );
}
</script>
</body>
```

Minha intenção é que ao disparar o evento `change` o valor de `limit` seja alterado para comportar mais caracteres e posteriormente quando o `select` perder o `focus` voltar para o valor inicial que é `3`(mas vamos por partes).

Comment: Queres mostrar mais caracteres quando estiver focado e menos quando não estiver focado, é isso?

Comment: Isso isso isso, izzas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```js
(function(selects) {
    var limite = 3;

    function verificarLimite(opts) {
        var originais = opts.map(function(option) {
            return option.innerHTML;
        });
        return function(e) {
            opts.forEach(function(option, i) {
                option.innerHTML = e.type == 'blur' ? originais[i].slice(0, limite) : originais[i];
            });
        }
    }
    selects.forEach(function(select) {
  var verificador = verificarLimite(Array.from(select.children));
        select.addEventListener('focus', verificador);
        select.addEventListener('blur', verificador);
        verificador({type:'blur'});
    });
})(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-limit]')));
```

```html
<select id="select_compra" data-limit="3">
    <option disabled selected style="display: none">Aaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
    <option>Bbbbbbbbb</option>
    <option>Ccccccc</option>
    <option>Ddddddddddd</option>
</select>
```

O código fica bem contido e faz o que queres.

Answer (score 2):

Mais uma resolução para o problema

```html
<body onload="getfoucs()">
<select id="select_compra" data-limit="3">
 <option disabled selected style="display: none" data-texto="Aaaaaaaaaaaaa">Aaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
 <option data-texto="Bbbbbbbbb">Bbbbbbbbb</option>
 <option data-texto="Ccccccc">Ccccccc</option>
 <option data-texto="Ddddddddddd">Ddddddddddd</option>
</select>
</body>
<script>
function LimitInput()
 {
  select = document.querySelector('[data-limit]');
     limit = select.getAttribute('data-limit');
     [].forEach.call
     (
      select.options, 
      function(option)
      {
       text = option.innerHTML.substring(0, limit);
       option.innerHTML = text;
      }
     );
 }
function getfoucs()
{
 LimitInput();
 select_compra.addEventListener
 (
  'focus', function()
  {    
    var elmnt = document.getElementById('select_compra');
    for(var i=0; i < elmnt.options.length; i++)
          {
            var texto = elmnt.options[i].getAttribute('data-texto');
            elmnt.options[i].innerHTML  = texto;
          }   
  }
 );
    select_compra.addEventListener
 (
  'blur', function()
  {    
   LimitInput();  
  }
 );
 
}
</script>
```